# Why does my monitor stay very dim after displaying black screens?

Tags: display, gaming, nvidia-graphics-card, brightness, lg-monitor

I've had this strange issue for a while. Basically if I launch certain games, which output a 100% black screen for an extended time (for example, when loading), the monitor will then go down to lowest brightness afterwards. It seems almost like the monitor doesn't complete the cycle of turning off when it see "nothing" on the screen. I can fix this either by turning the monitor off/on, or by going into the OSD and moving the brightness setting +1, then -1 (which instantly resets it). I've tried fiddling around with a few other OSD setting to see if that is the issue but haven't had any luck. I've also just dug around in the Nvidia control panel, but didn't see anything that could really be related to dimming the screen like it does.

My monitor is an LG34UM65, and GPU is a GTX 980. Not sure which is actually causing the problem. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What connection do you use? DVI, DisplayPort? Tried using a different port?

Comment: There is not usually a cycle of standby, when the screen is just black, normally that would be when there is "no signal" , or a specific screen stand-by..The moniors themselves can have a lot of automated features, including  ambient light sencing. and because adjusting the controls in the monitor changes things.  You could first wade through the array of menu items in the monitor itself, and test by shutting off "auto" features one by one, auto contrast , auto brightness, even various "profiles" (game desktop movie eco modes) could have automation features applied.

Comment: Auto features are not always called "auto" they may have cute names applied to special features of a monitor that "OFF" will still disable for testing.  From what you have stated so far, there is no reason to believe it is anything but the monitor.

Comment: Currently I'm using HDMI, unfortunately I don't have any other types of cables right now.

I've disabled all automated features of the monitor, but no luck. It seems like maybe there is a bug in the firmware of the monitor. The brightness after an all-black screen matches the setting of the lowest possible brightness I've found.

Comment: It doesn't come back out of the lowest brightness until I turn the monitor on/off. It can be on an entirely white/bright screen for minutes and still be stuck on the lowest brightness.

Comment: Ok that is different completely. (i will remove that comment)

Comment: You did not indicate the OS? new feature in windows called "adaptive brightness" exists in the power properties.

Comment: This happens on both Windows 7/10. I've had adaptive brightness disabled on both and still have the issue.